# Google Guice persistence + Spring Data JPA

Tags: jpa, guice, spring-data-jpa

I want to use Spring Data JPA in my web application build with Google Guice.

And I found out that Google Guice provide the `Guice Persist` and say "JPA (Java Persistence API) - with any compliant vendor implementation.".

Google Guice Persist - https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GuicePersist

Is it possible to use Spring Data JPA into Google Guice ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe [guice repository](https://code.google.com/p/guice-repository/) does what you want. It makes Spring Data JPA easy to use with Google Guice.

Comment: It's a pretty interesting project, but looks abandoned since long ago, which makes me think that there should be some better way.

Could it be that it's just more convenient to use spring-data-jpa as a library?

Comment: @Sobvan no we stopped looking. As I recall we ended up moving off guice. I think there were too many other spring projects we were making use of