# google guice equivalent of spring data jpa / apache deltaspike

Tags: jpa, guice

I'm looking for a project similar to spring data jpa / apache deltaspike that makes working with JPA quick and effective.

I came across here:
[Google Guice persistence + Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394252/google-guice-persistence-spring-data-jpa)

So, I know google guice repository exists, but it seems it is no longer maintained.

Do people that use Google Guice use some other library such as objectify?

Comment: I didn't really want to depend on Spring, so I'm using the criteria API with a thin wrapper so that the amount of redundant code is kept to a minimum.  I'm still wondering if there is a better solution or a project out there that does the same thing.